# In CrafterCMS, how can I add a number control that validates a certain range?

Tags: java, groovy, content-management-system, crafter-cms

I have a Google Maps component where authors can specify a latitude and a longitude.

I'm using a regular "Input" type control with a regex that validates if they are numbers, but, when trying to approach the problem of specifying a range (have the longitude verify that the value is within [-180, 180] and latitude within [-90, 90] )

However, having this validation through regex seems cumbersome, plus it would be nice to leverage `input type="number"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your own Form control following this 
http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/extending-studio/form-engine-control.html?highlight=control%20form